# i18n with Enumerize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, rails-i18n

I am using Enumerize gem https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize/
It allows me use beautiful selects in form with siple form. And all options in this selects are translated.

```
en:
  enumerize:
    user:
      sex:
        male: 'Man'
        female: 'Woman'
```

So, in my form I have select with variants 'Man' and 'Woman'. When I save the record with 'Man' value I get sex attribute with 'male' value. Now I want to display this value as 'Man' on the show page, but

```
= @user.sex
```

outputs as 'male' instead of 'Man'

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question.

Comment: @phoet look updated question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd probably use the `.text` method (you can see it inside the Gem by using `bundle open enumerize` and traversing the code a bit)

```
= @user.sex.text
```

You can also use the full translation key

```
= t("activerecord.enumerize.user.sex.#{@user.sex}")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put the selectable values in your yaml file, like

```
simple_form:
  options:
    user:
      gender:
        male: Male
        female: Female
```

simple form will pick them up for you. No need to do any explicit translation in your view

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n for more information!

To have the same level of "automation" in your other views, you could create a simple helper method that does the translation for you

```
def translate(record, attr)
  model = record.class.name.underscore
  value = record.send(attr)
  I18n.t("simple_form.options.#{model}.#{attr}.#{value}")
end
```

which you can call as

```
= translate(@user, :sex)
```

Comment: yeah, this is in forms. But I want to print "Male" or "Female" on my show page, not form

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to try [t_t gem](https://github.com/jalkoby/tt) which handles it ([#enums section](https://github.com/jalkoby/tt/blob/master/cheatsheet.md#enums) in Cheatsheet). Also it has a lot of other useful helper methods